# Python: how to convert object type to int with big values pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, custom-data-type

I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't seem to find the answer to this small problem.

I have some data, as follows

```
name     address     age         total_money
joko      china      56      4,5430012000007E+63
feni      korea      35      3,6000016489732E+90
rani     kamboja     54      1,470001179997E+133
```

and the data type each columns is:

```
name           3     non-null    object
address        3     non-null    object
age            3     non-null    int64
total_money    3     non-null    object
```

how to convert data type of total_money column to number/int because i want use the column for arithmetic operations

and I'm trying to convert data type

```
df = df.astype({'total_money': 'int64'})
```

but i get error:

```
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

how to handle the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your numbers are too big to be converted to `int`. Check this:

```
In [832]: df['total_money'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float).apply(lambda x: int(x))
Out[832]: 
0    4543001200000699948639040706606013103072417429...
1    3600001648973199763250405754747849609902640529...
2    1470001179997000081335562311854682630184495860...
Name: total_money, dtype: object
```

If you need an int representation of the values, I suggest you do the above. But the column dtype is still `object`.

If you'll try to convert this into `int`, you would get error:

`OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

This is because your numbers are exceeding the `maxsize` allowed by Python:

```
In [834]: import sys

In [835]: sys.maxsize
Out[835]: 9223372036854775807
```

So the suggestion would be to convert this into `float`:

```
In [837]: df['total_money'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
Out[837]: 
0     4.543001e+76
1    3.600002e+103
2    1.470001e+145
Name: total_money, dtype: float64
```

**EDIT after OP's comment on arithmetic operations:**

```
In [840]: df['total_money'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float).apply(lambda x: int(x))/ 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Out[840]: 
0                         45430012000006996125286400.0
1    3600001648973199969342672855872140055708849674...
2    1470001179997000080464234076318923714804535550...
Name: total_money, dtype: object
```

Comment: the resulting data type is float? how if i want to generate an int?

Comment: @NikenAmelia You can't convert it into `int`. Check my answer for explanation.

Comment: ohh but if i follow ur step: df['total_money'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float).apply(lambda x: int(x))

 the data type "object" will be able to perform arithmetic operations like + - / ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to perform arithmetic operations. Check the last part of my answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the logic, why is it divided by 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

can u explain for that? thank you
because i get error: OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Comment: No, it's just an example I took to show you that arithmetic operations are working.

Comment: @NikenAmelia the real question is, why would you absolutely want integers?